# How can we show that $E\:\hat\otimes_\pi\:E$ is isomorphic to a subspace of $\left(E'\:\hat\otimes_\pi\:E'\right)'$?

Tags: fa.functional-analysis, banach-spaces, tensor-products

Let

- $E$ be a $\mathbb R$-Banach space
- $E\:\hat\otimes_\pi\:E$ denote the projective tensor product

> How can we show that $E\:\hat\otimes_\pi\:E$ is isomorphic to a subspace of $\left(E'\:\hat\otimes_\pi\:E'\right)'$?

Clearly, if $\mathfrak B(E'\times E')$ denotes the space of bounded bilinear forms on $E'\times E'$, then $\mathfrak B(E'\times E')$ is isometrically isomorphic to $\left(E'\:\hat\otimes_\pi\:E'\right)'$.

So, we could conclude, if we would be able to show that $E\:\hat\otimes_\pi\:E$ can be embedded into $\mathfrak B(E'\times E')$.

Actually, I know that $E\otimes E$ (the algebraic tensor product) can be embedded into $\mathcal B(E^\ast\times E^\ast)$ (the set of bilinear forms on the cartesian product of the algebraic dual space $E^\ast$ with itself).

A canonical choice for this embedding would be $$\sum_{i=1}^nx_i\otimes y_i\mapsto\left((\varphi,\psi)\mapsto\sum_{i=1}^n\varphi(x_i)\psi(y_i)\right)\tag1\;.$$ If $\iota$ denotes this embedding, then it's easy to see that $\iota$ is a bounded linear operator from $E\otimes_\pi E$ (the algebraic tensor product $E\otimes E$ equipped with the projective norm) to $\mathfrak B(E'\times E')$ and hence admits a unique extension to a bounded linear operator $\overline\iota$ from $E\:\hat\otimes_\pi\:E$ to $\mathfrak B(E'\times E')$.

> If this approach is sensible at all, the only thing I need to conclude is the injectivity of $\overline\iota$. How can we show that?

Comment: Just to clarify: you are not trying to prove that $E\hat\otimes_\pi E$ is isomorphic to a *closed* subspace of ${\rm Bil}(E' \times E')$ are you?

Comment: Secondly, my immediate instinct is to worry if something goes wrong when E does not have the approximation property

Comment: @YemonChoi I've found the claim in the book *Semimartingales: A Course on Stochastic Processes* by Michel Métivier on [page 138](https://books.google.de/books?id=-DUyYSbqK3cC&pg=PA138&lpg=PA138&dq=%22appears+isomorphic+to+a+subspace+of+the+dual+space%22&source=bl&ots=aWD3xlzV-B&sig=X5VPLXS8UrWu8zMFuvzVtcb28HE&hl=de&sa=X&ved=0ahUKEwjBnp3dxe7YAhUMY1AKHSkaD-IQ6AEIJzAA#v=onepage&q=%22appears%20isomorphic%20to%20a%20subspace%20of%20the%20dual%20space%22&f=false). As I indicated in the question, I thought he means that $E\:\hat\otimes_\pi\:E$ is embedded into $\mathfrak B(E'\times E')$.

Comment: @YemonChoi It's fine for me to assume that $E$ has the approximation property; but he doesn't make this assumption.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

As suspected by Yemon Choi the question is very closely related to the *approximation property*: As can be seen e.g. in the book *Tensor Norms and Operator Ideals* of Defant and Floret (page 64 combined with the remark 5.4) a Banach space $E$ has the approximation property if and only if the canonical mapping $E\tilde{\otimes}_\pi F \to (E' \otimes_\pi F')'$ is injective for all Banach spaces $F$ (or only for $F=E'$). I don't know if it is written somewhere but I would be very surprised if the mapping would always be injective for $F=E$.

The question as stated (whether $E\tilde{\otimes}_\pi E$ is isomorphic to *some* subspace of $(E' \otimes_\pi E')'$ in a possibly non-canonical way) is, of course, very different.

Comment: Possibly something related to the infamous/celebrated Pisier space might work?

Answer (score 2):

Let $P$ be one of the Banach spaces constructed by Theorem 3.2 in [Pisier, "Counterexamples to a conjecture of Grothendieck"](https://projecteuclid.org/euclid.acta/1485890264).  That is, $P \widehat\otimes P = P \check\otimes P$.  Now, $P\check\otimes P$ embeds isometrically into $B(P',P) \subseteq B(P',P'') = (P' \widehat\otimes P')'$, and this embedding is exactly that described in the OP.  So for $P$, we obtain a positive answer.

As Jochen Wengenroth says, if $E$ has the approximation property then $E\widehat\otimes E \rightarrow B(E',E'')$ is injective. It seems to me that for "nice" spaces this is unlikely to be bounded below.